# How to programatically change ACRA 'interaction mode' setting

Tags: android, acra

I'm implementing ACRA in my Android App. I would like to be have it's interaction mode be silent by default, but if I see that a new version of my App is available, "Toast" the user upon crash with a message to update their copy of the App.

However it seems that ACRA interaction mode must be hard coded and loaded once upon init of application. Any way to set the mode at that point not via a hard coded setting? E.g. I'm looking to control the "mode = " setting which is copied below.

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class MyApplication extends Application ...
```

I see that [ACRA Issue 85](http://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=85) has added setters for resources for Toast parameters, but does it also have ability to configure interaction mode?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this? I didn't try but seems useful (at point of start)

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/acra/org/acra/ErrorReporter.java.htm

Comment: sorry, no I don't want to start modifying ACRA - and this file is for the back end reporting.